# Nice way to store the number of elements between braces?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Given an input like

```
a { b c d { e f } g }
```

I want to parse it one token at at time (letter or brace). When I hit the first closing brace `}` I need to know how many elements there were since the last opening brace (e and f = 2). And then when I hit the one after that, I need 4 (b,c,d,g).

Grabbing the tokens 1 by 1 is easy, but... I don't know how to count them. I was thinking about `Stack<int>` but I can't modify the top element to increment it?

Comment: Should the *a* outside the braces be ignored in this case?

Comment: @Oyvind: In this hypothetical scenario, yes. In practice... I think I'll have an implicit starting and ending brace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than trying to modify the top element, why not keep *that* one just in an `int` variable.

- When you see an opening brace, push your "count so far" onto the stack, and set the count to 0.
- When you see a letter, increment your "count so far"
- When you see a closing brace, do whatever you need to with the count, and pop the stack to get the new "count so far" value

EDIT: If you wanted to keep all the state in the stack itself, you can always think of the top element *as* a variable, which is changed by performing pop-increment-push. At that point, the operations are:

- Opening brace: push 0
- Letter: pop-increment-push
- CLosing brace: pop, use value however you want to before it vanishes forever

This is likely to be very slightly less efficient, but I think it's actually more elegant.

Comment: I was thinking up a solution using a recursive method that would work it's way inward, but I think this is a better solution since it's simpler, and the readability should be better.

Comment: I started on the pop-increment-push solution just before you posted this answer, but I actually found it to be less elegant. Turns out it's nice to be able to use the top count without having to peek :)